# flutter : Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDexDebug'

Tags: flutter, dart, gradle, flutter-layout

my apk won't get excuted causing this problem . My project is a brand new one, but having problems running the app on my device ( Note :#: i did add to my depencecies multidex and it didn't work
`implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:2.0.1'`)

```dart
 defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
     //   applicationId "com.example.yumor"
     //   minSdkVersion 19
        // minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
     //   targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
     //   versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
     //   versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

                                                                                                       
}


dependencies {
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:29.1.0')
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"

}
~~~!


    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
    
    * What went wrong:
    Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDexDebug'.
    > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
       > Failed to transform classes.jar (project :sqflite) to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr=debug, com.android.build.api.attributes.VariantAttr=debug, dexing-enable-desugaring=true, dexing-incremental-transform=false, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=19, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
          > Execution failed for DexingWithClasspathTransform: C:\Users\Abdou\flutter project\realfultter\yumor\build\sqflite\intermediates\runtime_library_classes_jar\debug\classes.jar.
             > Unable to read jar file C:\Users\Abdou\flutter project\realfultter\yumor\build\sqflite\intermediates\runtime_library_classes_jar\debug\classes.jar
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is set to 20 or lower, you need to configure your app for multiDex support.

```
 defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.inspire.aaym"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30
    }
```

So, if your app is not intended to be used in the Android version prior to 5.0, setting the minSdkVersion number to 21 will easily fix this issue.